# Replace a character in a file and copy the contents to a temp file and rename the temp file to original file

Tags: android

I want to replace a character in a file and copy the contents to a temp file and rename the temp file to original file.

```
path = "/mnt/sdcard/TESTfile/"
File _f = new File(path);
File[] _f1 = _f.listFiles();
String[] s1 = { "t1.txt", "t2.txt", "t3.txt" };
_fOut = new FileOutputStream(path + File.separator + s1[i]);

// Copy the bits from input stream to output stream
StringBuffer sb = null;
BufferedWriter out = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replaceAll("a"," ").replaceAll("g"," ");
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    Log.i("Line>>>" + line, "<<<<<");
    sb.append(line);

    s = sb.toString();
    byte[] temp = s.getBytes();
    _fOut.write(temp);
}
fis.close();
_fOut.close();

//old file name with path
String path1 = path + File.separator + s1[i];

 //new file name with path
String rename1 = path + File.separator + _f1[i].getName();
File oldFile = new File(path1);
File renameFile = new File(rename1);

for(int j = 0; j < _f1.length;j++)
{

oldFile.renameTo(renameFile);
}
```

This is how i tried to do it. I am not sure how to rename the file and delete the original file. Please help

Comment: Could you add only the relevant codes, instead of whole file.

Comment: Hi Starx i have  edited my code and only added relevant code... I hope it is clear. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename a file, you need 2 [File](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fjava%2Fio%2FFile.html&ei=wXKiUOGFGYe9iwKXvICQAw&usg=AFQjCNEtAK3ekRtPBSGiZ2TpNFWiCiEayQ&sig2=06wr0A5JRJThveCjEYyJ7w) objects. Create one using the original path and the second using the new name. Then call `original.renameTo(newFile)`.

Deleting a file is even easier. Android contexts have a method called [`deleteFile(name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile%28java.lang.String%29). Call it to delete a file. Keep in mind that that method deletes a file from the local storage folders only and doesn't accept path separators. If you want to delete a file from a different location, there is a [`file.delete()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) method you could use too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the result as required.I am concerned if it is correct because as you can see in the code i am not deleting the file only renaming it. Is there any other approach please help.

Comment: there are plenty of changes i would make to your code to make it more efficient and more "correct". if you need to delete the file, use `file.delete()`. i would strongly suggest that if this code is supposed to be production, you do some MAJOR rework

Comment: i am new to coding still learning any suggestion of rework will be help full. Thank you

Comment: what's your email? i'll copy the code you have and send you my suggestions